# Does anybody know how to disable connman?

Tags: networking, connman

I have a BeagleBone running Ubuntu.  connman is getting in my way and I'd like to disable it.  I deleted `/etc/rc*/*connman`, but somehow it's still getting started.

(Why am I trying to disable it?  Because I'm trying to set a static IP address for eth0 in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but that doesn't work because evidently connman brings up eth0 first, with no address, which keeps `ifup` from working.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also configure `connman` to ignore a specific interface.

I had to do exactly the same (static IP for eth0) and could do so by
configuring it in `/etc/network/interfaces` AND
by modifying (adding) a line in `/etc/connman/main.conf`:

```
NetworkinterfaceBlacklist=eth0,SoftAp0,usb0,usb1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
In the end, I guess, connman or something like it is the way of the future, and we're supposed to use it to configure all network interfaces and stop using /etc/network/interfaces, because /etc/network/interfaces is on the way out.

Comment: This worked for me with a 2018 image. I could not get connman to configure or startup properly with a static IP without a cable plugged in, which ruined my DHCP server that was trying to start...

Answer (score 3):

I never did figure out how to disable it, so I ended up just deleting it:

```
sudo apt remove connman
```

Now my conventional, static IP configurations (in `/etc/network/interfaces`) are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may try running this in the command line:

```
sudo systemctl disable connman.service
```

After that other Network Managers should work. Normally Connman is designed
for embedded devices.

This worked for me when I had some trouble with Connman on a fresh Ubuntu Studio 21.04 installation (lost Internet connection).